# Learn python the hard way exercise 20 line numbers

Tags: python, function

Doing [Exercise 20 (Functions and Files) of *Learn Python the Hard Way*](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex20.html), here's my code:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()
    
def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)
    
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()
    
current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

And when run it should be like this:

```
First let's print the whole file:

This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3

Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1 This is line 1

2 This is line 2

3 This is line 3
```

But the problem is that there are no line numbers after rewind, it's like:

```
First let's print the whole file:

     This is line 1
    This is line 2
    This is line 3

    Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
    Let's print three lines:
      This is line 1

     This is line 2

     This is line 3
```

There IS a single space before the first "This" both times, and also there's a dark rectangle before it:

[image]

I can't figure out what the problem is, would be glad if anyone can help.

Comment: Probably there's some hidden unicode character at the start of your file.

Comment: Unicode BOM, I would guess...

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://oi59.tinypic.com/x659s.jpg ;
Editor is Notepad++

Comment: Your program works fine if I try it in my python console.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the result of interpreting text in 'utf16le' as 'ascii', and printing it to the windows console.  You can fix this in two ways.  Notepad++ calls this 'UCS-2 little endian'.

Option 1:, in Notepad++, select "ANSI" from the encoding menu and save the text file (the one containing "This is line 1" et-cetera) file again.  The problem should go away.

Option 2: Make your program unicode aware, swap:

```
current_file = open(input_file)
```

with

```
import codecs
current_file = codecs.open(input_file, 'r', 'utf-16-le')
```

Since you're trying to learn python (the hard way), i'd reccomend option 1, but you will eventually have to come to terms with unicode awareness in your programs.